# How to build an apk on Android Studio

Tags: android

I made an apk file to upload my app to the Play Store. I am getting an error that I need to update the API lever from 26 to 29. I have updated the api level to 29 (android 10) and I am trying to build the signed apk but I am getting an error

```
    Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)       com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats     .IntellijIndexingStats$Index
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.counters.IndexCounters.<clinit>(IndexCounters.java:34)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.<init>(MapReduceIndex.java:85)
at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex$CompilerMapReduceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:232)
at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:79)
at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.<init>(JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.java:12)
at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.initialize(JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.java:79)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.buildStarted(JavaBuilder.java:148)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:363)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:139)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:302)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:135)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:228)
at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

build gradle

```
                    buildscript {
                        repositories {
                            jcenter()
                            maven {
                                url "https://maven.google.com"
                            }
                        }
                        dependencies {

                            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
                            // in the individual module build.gradle files
                            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
                        }
                    }

                    allprojects {
                        repositories {
                            jcenter()
                            maven {
                                url "https://maven.google.com"
                            }
                        }
                        //This replaces project.properties w.r.t. build settings
                        project.ext {
                        defaultBuildToolsVersion="25.0.2" //String
                        defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
                        defaultTargetSdkVersion=26 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
                        defaultCompileSdkVersion=26 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
                        }
                    }

                    task clean(type: Delete) {
                        delete rootProject.buildDir
                    }
```

Comment: check your dependencies are proper with the API level change.

Comment: in which file are the dependencies? i have assets, res, META-INF, third_party

Comment: check your dependencies in build.gradle, is the app building properly ?

Comment: post your build.gradle file

Comment: on AndroidManifest.xml  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

Comment: I ve done tha app on Ionic and then created the apk file, so i opened the apk file on Android Studio

Comment: i posted the build_cradle

Answer (score 0):

i did

```
ionic cordova platform rm android

ionic cordova platform add android@latest
```

and it worked